# Why isn't url_for rendering this like I think it should?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my controller:

```
@statics = [{'home' => 'about'},
            {'home' => 'termsandconditions'},
            {'home' => 'information'},
            {'news' => 'archives'}]
```

and in my view:

```
@statics.each do |controller, action|
  xml.loc url_for(:only_path => false, :controller => controller, :action => action)
  xml.lastmod     w3c_date(Time.now)
  xml.changefreq  "weekly"
  xml.priority    0.8
end
```

the URLs aren't what I would expect, e.g.

```
http://localhost:3000/homeinformation
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:3000/information
```

However, I just did this manually, I get the right URL:

```
url_for(:only_path => false, :controller => 'brownies', :action => 'index') #works!
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@statics` is an array with one hash entry, so you'll need your `each` block to take just a single parameter and split it up inside the block.